# Launch EA Programmatically

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

I would like to open an EA session via Windows service and do some action behind the scenes.
I use the Repository API, however, don't know how to initialize it correctly.

```
    EA.Repository repository = ?;
    repository.OpenFile(@"C:\test.eap");
    repository.Exit();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: assign a value to `repository`? If you try and call a method on something that's set to `null` what else do you expect to happen?

Comment: @TZHX, That is exactly why I ask how to initialize the repository.

Comment: did you try `EA.Repository repository = new Repository();` ? I'm afraid I'm not familiar with the library you are using but that'd be the first thing to try. Google doesn't seem to suggest any custom constructors that I can see.

Comment: @TZHX Thanks. When I try to initialize it like how you suggest I get the following error: `Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID XXX failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed. Any help would be great.

Comment: Hi, as I said - I'm not familiar with the library. I suggest editing that attempt and the errors you get from it into your question (also perhaps add the `c#` tag for wider visibility?). [This page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/870655) suggests it might be something around your windows account permissions -- but I'm not sure. Sorry that I couldn't be of more help. :)

Comment: Is using the COM library from a Windows Service supported?

Comment: @CodeCaster, Thanks for reply. What do you mean?

Comment: I mean "is this even supposed to work"? Does it work from a console application?

Comment: @CodeCaster, Yes, it is. The problem is when I use Windows Service. I enable UI interaction, by the way.

Comment: Ah, that is your problem right there. You can't run EA from a service. (or it is very difficult at least). Check this [whitepaper](http://blog.lieberlieber.com/2012/09/03/ea-as-an-unattended-windows-service-on-windows-server-2008r2-and-higher/) for more information

Answer (score 1):

the code sample below demonstrate how to open EA COM Object and open EA project file then get list of the project models

```
// connect to EA COM object     
EA.Repository _repository = new EA.RepositoryClass();
// Open EA project file
bool fileOpened = _repository.OpenFile(filePath);
if(fileOpened)
   Collection models = _repository.Models; // collection of models inside of opened project
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to Interop.EA.dll and use

```
EA.Repository repository = new EA.RepositoryClass();
```

Comment: Thanks. Using **new EA.RepositoryClass()** I get the following error: `Interop type 'EA.RepositoryClass' cannot be embedded. Use the applicable interface instead.` Therefore I try **new EA.Repository()** that fails at runtime (COM with Windows Sevice issue).  Any help would be great!

Comment: Have you added a reference to Interop.EA.dll ?

Comment: Sure I added. Converting the project to .NET 3.5 allows to use RoesitoryClass instead of Repository interface. However, I get the error at runtim: `Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID XXX failed due to the following error: 80080005.`

Comment: And this is when you run simply run the exe ? Or are you trying to execute this from an unattended service?

Answer (score 0):

To open a running instance use (C++ example)

```
CLSID clsid;
CLSIDFromProgID(L"EA.App", &clsid);
IUnknown *pUnk = NULL;
IDispatch *pDisp = NULL;
HRESULT hr = GetActiveObject(clsid, NULL, (IUnknown**)&pUnk);
if(SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
  hr = pUnk->QueryInterface(IID_IDispatch, (void **)&pDisp);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it safe C# code? How do I access the repository?

Comment: I guess you can use it also with C#. I'm not an expert in either language, though. `pDisp` should contain the interface from where you can retrieve the repository.

Comment: Well, This opens EA session AFAIK, How can I access the repository?

Comment: To create an instance is a bit more tricky (I googled for CreateObject which you would use in VB).

Comment: The c# equivalent to that is: `object obj = Marshal.GetActiveObject("EA.App");
      EA.App eaApp = obj as EA.App;
      EA.Repository repository = eaApp.Repository;`

Comment: But your problem is the fact that you try to do it in a service, not the code you are using to create instance of EA.

Comment: Yep. The service issue has been discussed long and broad on Sparx' forum.